# Safety of Using DELEGATECALL with Mappings

Tags: solidity, storage, delegatecall

To make my contract upgradable, I have a proxy contract that stores all of my data.

As I understand it, when using delegatecall the storage layout needs to match for both the caller and callee. Due to the nature of my contract, I have many mappings that are subject to change on upgrades. Do these need to be defined in both contracts? Am I at risk of corrupting storage if not?

My thought is no, since mappings are not stored the same way and do not have fixed sizes. I want to be sure though.

Comment: This article https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-the-hidden-costs-of-arrays-28e119f04a9b explain how mapping are allocated in the contract storage. If you only modify code, ie functions, you should be ok. If you add/remove a storage variable, you are changing the storage layout and an upgrade will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your map data should be fine. As in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-the-hidden-costs-of-arrays-28e119f04a9b) The formula for calculating the storage address for a map key is `keccak256(bytes32(key) + bytes32(position))`.

The main risk is if you change the version of the solidity compiler in the new delegate contract and they change the formula above. I would suggest having a test against the assembly code to ensure the computed addresses are the same, or just never change the version of solidity you are using.